# How to remove _next from path in build folder in Next Js

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend

How to remove "_next" from path in build folder in Next Js. we are using 13.2.4 version.

Here is a example :

Please help us.

Answer (score -1):

Change distDir in next.config

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: 'build'
};
```

Comment: It just create build folder in my project that I already done.
My question is how to remove _next in my path in build folder.
<link rel="preload" href="../../_next/static/css/e85fa35ba11f1ab4.css" as="style"/>

Comment: "The _next folder in Next.js is an automatically generated folder that contains build artifacts and caches used during the Next.js build process. It is typically located in the root directory of a Next.js project and includes files such as the compiled JavaScript and CSS files, as well as images and other static assets. The _next folder is automatically generated by Next.js during the build process and should not be modified manually, as doing so could result in build errors or other issues."